# Kafka mirror maker 0.10.2.0 is not working

Tags: apache-kafka

I use kafka  0.10.2.0 and Im trying to use the kafka mirror maker option.

consumer.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=ip_source1:9092, ip_source2:9092
group.id=mirror_maker_2
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
```

producer.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=ip_dest1:9092, ip_dest2:9092
auto.create.topics.enable=true
```

consumer & producer are with version kafka 0.10.1.

I run the kaffka mirror maker script by the following command:

```
opt/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --producer.config opt/kafka/config/producer.properties --consumer.config opt/kafka/config/consumer.properties --whitelist *  --num.streams 10
```

I send message to topic: "a" in ip_source1 and with kafka-console-consumer I see the message.

But In ip_dest1 and ip_des2, I don't see the message. Moreover, I don't see it in my kafka-mirror-maker machine, when I watch topic "a".

In debug mode there is no error - just: `"DEBUG Received successful Heartbeat response for group mirror_maker_2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whitelist is a Java regex. Try ".*" including the quotes instead of just *. Also you can use just the topic name for testing to eliminate regex being the problem.